# Why is bootstrap not calling the active class?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am receiving information from a PHP file via jQuery Ajax and looping the information as shown below. I need it to call a `<tr class="active">` and put them into the `<tr><td>` format that bootstrap provides. But, unfortunately, this is not happening.

Does anybody have any suggestions? Thank you :)

```
function getStudentList() {
     $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
       type: "GET",
       url: "getView.php",             
       dataType: "json",   //expect html to be returned                
       success: function(response){                    
          $.each(response, function(index, response){

          $( "#aaa" ).append('<tr class="active"><td>' + response['Student_ID'] + '</td><td>' + response['FirstName'] + "</td><td>" + response['LastName'] + "</td><td>" + response['Student_ID'] + "</td><td>" + response['Year'] + '</td></tr>');
        });

    },
     error: function(e) {
        //called when there is an error
        console.log("Error: " + e.message);
        }
    });
}
```

---------- HEADER.PHP ---------------

```
  <!-- Database Config Files -->
<?php include('db_config.php'); ?>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Custom css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="export.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="contact.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="create.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="edit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="delete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show the xhr result response(ajax response) displayed in console?

Comment: is the ow getting appended ? a working example can help more in looking into the issue

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap v4, you need to use the table-active class on the tr element. `<tr class="table-active">`

Comment: @Azy you need to follow up with your questions.

Comment: [link]http://imgur.com/a/7lchi - Here is a screen shot. The class has been added but is just not being read. @CodeGodie I am overseas apologies! 

The active class above is done manually in HTML where as the second active class is appended from the AJAX.

http://imgur.com/a/NmHm9 - Header File where JQuery & Bootstrap are included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start using a better IDE; I recommend PHPStorm. The problem seems to be syntax with your quotes. Check these areas:

you have:

```
<td>' + response['Student_ID'] + '</td>
```

should be:

```
<td>' + response["Student_ID"] + '</td>
```

better yet:

```
<td>' + response.Student_ID + '</td>
```

Comment: Changed it to response.Student_ID still nothing. Is that due to the fact that its an object? Why is it able to be read as a array? Technically it is getting the desired result but clearly the "active" class is not being picked up which is odd because above it the manual HTML is. So is there an interference coming from AJAX?

Comment: hmm.. show your PHP code and I will be able to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry not sure how to paste it or a php code bin -

[<?php
 include('db_config.php'); 

 $sql="SELECT * FROM Students";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $students[] = $row;
 }

 $size = sizeof($students);


 if ( isset( $_GET['Student_ID'] ) && !empty( $_GET['Student_ID'])) {
  $stud_id = $_GET['Student_ID'];
 }
 else {
  $stud_id = null;
 }

 echo json_encode($students);
?>

Comment: In your PHP, place this `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before your `echo` and let me know what you get.

Comment: Also in your JS, after `success: function(response){ `, place `console.log(response);` and show what results you see in your browser's web inspector console.

Comment: What is a good paste bin to use for PHP? - here is the image [link]http://pasteboard.co/i7UgPdiPM.png

Comment: you can click "edit" on your original question on top, then add your PHP code to your original question.

Comment: everything should be working fine. .. How are you including the Javascript `<script>` tags? show your HTML as well.

Comment: The code  won't come up to edit it in but here is an image - http://pasteboard.co/i88LG0mzc.png

Comment: you should be able to copy and paste your code directly on to the original question.. Also, i see the image, but its not showing me anything related to your question.

Comment: still dont see the HTML that relates to your question.. Where's the HTML element  with ID `"#aaa"`

Comment: oh my god :/ mate thank you so much. I replicated id="aaa" twice (idiot) and it was interfering with my desired one. Now that I removed it, it is fixed :/ I feel so stupid thank you so much for your help !!

Comment: No prob. Glad I was able to help.